# How can I find out how many Miles I will receive on Royal Plus?

Tags: loyalty-programs, oneworld, cathay-pacific, royal-jordanian

I'm flying from Zurich to Auckland with Cathay Pacific via Hong-Kong next year, and am considering getting the miles accredited to a Royal Jordanian Frequent Flyer account (Royal Plus), as they have fewer miles requirements for elite status, 15k, 40k and 100k instead of 30k, 60k and 120k (at Cathay Pacific's Marco Polo) for OneWorld Ruby, Sapphire and Emerald.

I would earn 22k miles in Cathay Pacific's programme, and am flying fare classes K and V.

I have checked their [milage calculator](https://fly.rj.com/MileageCalculator/) for the flights, but could not find the connections that I have.

Is their any way I can find out how many miles I would get in Royal Plus from these Cathay Pacific flights? If there are other airlines that offer similarly easy status, I would also be willing to join their programme.

Comment: Note that you are incorrect in assuming those are the mileage limits for OneWorld - for example on American's AAdvantage scheme, Executive Platinum (Emerald) requires only 100k miles. There are no common criteria for how you qualify for OneWorld status - each airline has its own rules.

Comment: Yes I acknowledge that, which is why I listed two different limits for the One World statuses by two different airlines. I'm not implying that there are no other mileage limits at other airlines. I even suggest it in the last sentence. I've edited to make it more clear

Answer (score 3):

The Royal Jordanian [Royal Plus partner airlines earning calculator](https://fly.rj.com/MileageCalculator/) looks to suffer the problem that most airline calculators do, which is they fail to update it often enough with the possible airports that their partners fly to

Frankfurt is on their list for Cathay Pacific, and is a similar distance.
[Zurich-Hong Kong is 5776 miles / 9296 km](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=ZRH-HKG), while [Frankfurg-Hong Kong is 5697 miles / 9169 km](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=FRA-HKG)

The [RJ calculator](https://fly.rj.com/MileageCalculator/) says that flying FRA-HKG on CX would earn you 2843 points in classes `B H K L M V`, so basically 50% (+- a few points for rounding). Therefore, ZUR-HKG in K or V would be about 2880 points. Auckland is on the list, so that one's easy - in discounted economy classes `B H K L M V` it's 2848 points. Assuming you booked a return, you're looking at about 11,500 points.

There are a number of other OneWorld airlines you could look to credit your miles to. I don't think there's one that's known for being "the easiest one to get status with on discounted economy tickets", so you'll need to play with the calculators for several of them. Be aware that some have restrictions on the minimum number of flights needed with that airline (eg BA needs a minimum of 4 BA flights for British Airways Executive Club Silver = OneWorld Sapphire, in addition to the tier point minimum). Also be aware that AA are changing their AAdvantage program quite a bit at the moment, so you need to ensure you check the right earnings for the exact dates you fly if you wanted to credit to them.